# How to declare integer expression constant in x86 Assembly MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Running into a syntax problem when trying to declare an integer expression constant.

I have one constant, a `DWORD` named `MAX` with a value of `30`. I want to declare another `DWORD` named `MIN` that is 15% of 30, `MAX*0.15`, or `4`. I've tried `MIN DWORD MAX*0.15`; but that hasn't worked.

I need to use a `DWORD` as I have to move the value to the `eax` register. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you're using a load from a data address, rather than a `mov eax, imm32`, you can use `movzx eax, byte ptr [max]`, if your constants fit in 8 bits.  (`movsx` to sign-extend instead).  Similarly for vector constants, `pmovzx` can save space if you don't need to use them directly as memory operands.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of multiplying by 0.15 you could multiply by 15 and dividing by 100. However, something like this won't work:

```
foo DWORD 50
bar DWORD (foo*15)/100
```

Because the assembler needs the value to be constant. So you'll have to do this instead:

```
FOO_VALUE equ 50
foo DWORD FOO_VALUE
bar DWORD (FOO_VALUE*15)/100
```